# What is the Difference between Data Transformation vs Transportation?

Tags: migration, data-warehouse, etl

Is there a difference in meaning between "*data transformation*" and "*data transportation*" in ETL process and data warehousing? or both concepts can be used interchangeably in this context?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Transportation is just moving data from one place to another - in ETL, from source system to either staging area, data warehouse or data mart.

Transformation is changing data structure so that it meets data warehouse needs - i.e. star schema, denormalization, aggregation, calculations, data cleansing, data enrichment etc.

Both happen while ETL, but the "T" from "ETL" stands for Transformation.